# s4sdk openSAP develop extension Course - Address not created - no put operation in mock server log

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have created mock server and it shows GET operation selecting all partners and will get a partner by id.

If I click on the Add address button there is no put or post operation in the log file.

Mock server log:

> Request: GET
> /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner(BusinessPartner='1003764')?$select=BusinessPartner,CreationDate,FirstName,IsFemale,IsMale,LastName,to_BusinessPartnerAddress/AddressID,to_BusinessPartnerAddress/BusinessPartner,to_BusinessPartnerAddress/CityName,to_BusinessPartnerAddress/Country,to_BusinessPartnerAddress/HouseNumber,to_BusinessPartnerAddress/PostalCode,to_BusinessPartnerAddress/StreetName&$expand=to_BusinessPartnerAddress&$format=json
> Reading business partner 1003764

Log from application

> 12:51:35.357 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery - Successfully
> connected to destination service.

Am I missing a setting?

Comment: How did you implement the add operation? Would you mind sharing the code with us so that we can have a look?

Comment: Here is the class:public CreateAddressCommand(final BusinessPartnerService service, final BusinessPartnerAddress addressToCreate) {
        super(HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandSetter(
                CreateAddressCommand.class,
                HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandProperties().withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(10000)
        ));
        this.service = service;
        this.addressToCreate = addressToCreate;
    }

Comment: @Override
    public BusinessPartnerAddress run() throws Exception {

       return service.createBusinessPartnerAddress(addressToCreate).execute();

    }

Comment: This is now working. How do I show this as resolved?

Comment: Just provide the resolution as answer yourself and mark it as answered so that it is documented for others having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an add functionality for a Business Partner Address in the following way:

```java
 BusinessPartnerAddress addressToCreate = BusinessPartnerAddress.builder()
            .businessPartner(businessPartnerId)
            .streetName("someStreet")
            .build();

 new DefaultBusinessPartnerService()
            .createBusinessPartnerAddress(addressToCreate)
            .execute();
```